# Blender 2.62 not rendering objects

Tags: 12.04, blender

Installed Blender (2.62) from Software Center. The interface loads good but objects are not visible in any view. It shows that objects are selected but they appear no where. Even the default cube, lamp and camera are not visible.

Net-book Specs,

```
Intel Dual Core 1.6 GHz Processor
RAM 1GB
Resolution 1024*600
Graphics: Intel GMA 3600
OS: Ubuntu 12.04.1
Desktop Enviroment: LXDE and Unity
```

I have cedar-view graphics driver installed as suggested in additional drivers, it gives me native resolution and hardware accelerated X. I can play some games with nice frame-rates, like Irrlamb, Lugaru, XMoto and AssaultCube. Glxgears gives an average of 120 FPS.

Any reason why Blender is not working correctly?